# Live Tiles on Windows 8 seems to be crashing

Tags: windows-8, live-tiles

I have installed Windows 8 Pro. Everything was going on fine, until today, Live tiles have stopped working. For example, clicking on the "Mail" app doesn't do anything. Other tiles also don't seem to do anything when clicked. Clicking on "Store" app, opens the flash screen for a sec or two, and then takes me back to the home screen.

Searched for that, and found a [few links explaining the problem.](http://techie-buzz.com/tech-news/tiles-not-working-update-windows-8.html) They recommend  to not use Avast. But, I am using AVG, in case that matters. Even after uninstalling AVG, the problem persists.

I found another post, suggesting to run the command `sfc /scannow`, but that didn't fix the problem either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try going into the Windows Personalization app (the Metro version of the Control Panel), and try refreshing Windows 8. It has some options that essentially reset Windows 8 with the option of saving your files and apps. Perhaps an errant program messed up something in your installation and caused Windows 8 apps to fail to work properly.

Comment: Ah... the refresh seems to be stuck at 99%. A few days into using windows 8, and it doesn't make me happy. :(

Comment: It's very possible that something messed up your installation. I would make sure you get a backup of all your important data and, if you can't find an elegant solution, be ready to take the more drastic step of reinstalling or at least doing a reset that doesn't save your data...

Unfortunately I don't have a better solution than this. It might depend on what exactly happened, here. More information (like any errors you can find in the Event Viewer that may be related), and what you did between when it worked and when things started breaking would help.

Comment: Atlast, recovered from the refresh. Refresh seems to help, but at a cost. I had to install all my drivers and applications. :(

Comment: @KumarBibek Well, I'm glad you at least recovered.

Answer (score 0):

The apps need updating. Go to app store & right click near the top of screen. You will see  the words Home and Your apps appear on the left. Click on your apps then use the drop down menu to select installed apps. In the top right corner you should see updates or update your apps. Click on it and it will update all your installed apps. Then, hey presto, they all work again. Why don't they just tell us this stuff in first place & make life a lot easier.

Comment: How do you know they need updating?

Comment: Mine stopped working & I ended up doing the refresh & lost everything. They started to work again, but soon stopped. I was looking at the sport app & Microsoft recommended updating it. A bit of trial & error got me there in the end. Using the method I described, actually updated them all & they started to work again - and still are!